# How to reference an input fields value in Riot.js?

Tags: javascript, riot.js, custom-tags

```
<hello-world>
  <form action="">
    <input type="text" ref="inputValue" placeholder="type a name" />
    <input type="submit" onclick="{trigger_printName}" />
  </form>

  <script>

    this.trigger_printName = e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(e.target.value);
      console.log(this.refs.inputValue.value)
    };
  </script>
</hello-world>
```

I am trying to access the value of the users input in the input field. Console logging e.target.value returns an empty string and console logging this.refs.inputValue.value says "Cannot read property 'inputValue' of undefined"

Comment: I've used the exact code you've provided in this example and it seems like it's working just fine, maybe you're missing something in your given example?
Take a look here :
https://next.plnkr.co/edit/YLj9v2FZVGzckC38

Comment: yeah i compared mine to yours and its identical yet yours works and mine does not haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had some how installed a very old version of riot+compiler.min.js. after updating the file to the current v3.13.2 it works just fine.